# Factorizing $n$-th Wendt determinant $W(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

It has been conjectured that the $p$-th Wendt determinant $W(p)$, where $p$ is prime, has all its prime factors that are greater than $p$ congruent to $1$ (mod $p$). Furthermore its prime factors that are less than $p$, when fully exponeniated to divide $W(p)$ are also congruent to $1$ (mod $p$), if they exist. However the occurrences of $W(p)$ with $p$ prime such that it has prime factors less than $p$ is uncommon [(see OEIS A336688)](https://oeis.org/A336688).

Are such occurrences finite or is there an example greater than $W(331)$?